# Element-wise operations on scipy.sparse.coo_matrix (e.g. modulo)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can I perform element-wise operations (e.g. modulo) for a [scipy.sparse.coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html)?

Do I have to create a NumPy dense array from it? If that's the case won't I lose all the benefits gained from creating a sparse matrix?

Comment: That is probably a glitch in the library since the elementwise modulus operation as well as integer division do not seem to be supported by that, although they would not change the sparsity of the matrix.

Comment: The sparse package doesn't try to replicate everything in `numpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the element-wise operation does not change the sparsity of the data, you can use the `.data` attribute, e.g.:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse


m = (sp.sparse.rand(5, 10, 0.2) * 100).astype(int)
print(m)
```

```
  (1, 0)        34
  (1, 2)        2
  (2, 2)        39
  (1, 4)        54
  (3, 4)        22
  (4, 4)        46
  (1, 6)        40
  (1, 7)        97
  (4, 8)        60
  (4, 9)        97
```

```
m.data %= 10
print(m)
```

```
  (1, 0)        4
  (1, 2)        2
  (2, 2)        9
  (1, 4)        4
  (3, 4)        2
  (4, 4)        6
  (1, 6)        0
  (1, 7)        7
  (4, 8)        0
  (4, 9)        7
```

This should be efficient and should not have any *conversion* overhead.

Note that this can be done for any operation for which zero `0` is the [absorbing element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element), at least on one side (left or right) for non-symmetric (commutative) operations.

For example, in the modulo `%` operation, `0` is the left-absorbing element, since `0 % a = 0` for any `a`. The same is true for integer division `//`, division `/` (as long as `0.0` and `-0.0` distinction is not needed) and exponentiation `**` (for positive numbers). For multiplication `*`, `0` is the absorbing element.

For the case of element-wise multiplication `*` and `/` (by a scalar at least) are supported with the regular syntax by `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` objects.

Comment: Note also that in some cases you can rewrite / transform to _make_ `0` the absorbing element, by e.g. storing an offset separately and pushing that downstream. If you're wanting to calculate, say, `N = M.cos(); res = N.sum()`, you can rewrite that to `Nm1 = M.cos() - 1; res = (Nm1+1).sum()` and then to `Nm1 = M.cos() - 1; res = Nm1.sum()+1.sum()`. The `1.sum()` portion is trivial; it's just `Nm1.size()`. So overall you have `Nm1 = M.copy(); Nm1.data = Nm1.data.cos() - 1; res = Nm1.sum() + Nm1.size()`. It's too bad there wasn't a builtin sparse matrix type that stored a global offset like this.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, it's not just `sparse_input % whatever`. That's not supported. Instead, for a scalar RHS, you can manipulate the COO format directly:

```
coo_lhs = whatever
scalar_rhs = whatever
coo_result = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(
    (coo_lhs.data % scalar_rhs, (coo_lhs.row.copy(), coo_lhs.col.copy())),
    shape=coo_lhs.shape)
```

It doesn't make sense to have a sparse matrix as the RHS of a modulo operation - if you're sure you want that, convert to dense.

Comment: You could do an in-place change, `M.data = M.data % x`.  It doesn't add nonzero values, so that's safe.  The new zeros don't harm anything,   A `csr` format has an `eliminate_zeros` method that can be used to clean these out.

Comment: It's throwing row and col is not defined

Comment: @MayRestinPeace: Sounds like either you made a typo, or you're not actually using a COO matrix.

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. I was multiplying the matrices causing their type to be changed